# How do I get column -t to only have on space between columns?

Tags: bash, vim

I often find myself lining up code using bash's `column` command in vim like this:

```
:'<,'>!column -t
```

This effectively does this:

```
echo -e "func(arg1, arg2)\nfunc(some_arg, another_arg)" | column -t

# output:
func(arg1,      arg2)
func(some_arg,  another_arg)
```

I'd really like to make it so there's only one space separating the columns like this:

```
func(arg1,     arg2)
func(some_arg, another_arg)
```

Is there any easy way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you read `man column`:

> -o, --output-separator string
>                 Specify the columns delimiter for table output (default is two spaces).

so:

```
kent$  echo -e "func(arg1, arg2)\nfunc(some_arg, another_arg)" | column -t -o" "
func(arg1,     arg2)
func(some_arg, another_arg)
```

Comment: Ahh, I don't have that option. Macs must ship with an old version of column. That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-c` :      Output is formatted for a display columns wide.

```
$ echo -e "func(arg1, arg2)\nfunc(some_arg, another_arg)" | column -c -t
func(arg1, arg2)
func(some_arg, another_arg)
```

If you deal with columns a lot in `vim`, you might want to take a look at the 
[tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin.

Update: A way to do it with `Tabular` plugin:

[image]

Comment: When I do that I get the same output as you, but that's not what I'm looking for. Really I'd like the second arguments to be lined up, but only have one space between the comma and 'another_arg'.

Comment: @bmaddy: Added a demo to do it with `Tabular` plugin.